# Can I play Destiny on my Xbox one against my brothers who both have Xbox 360?

Tags: destiny, xbox-network

I'm not sure if the different generation consoles are compatible over Xbox live...

Answer (score 3):

No, cross-generation play is not possible in Destiny.

If you have an Xbox 360 and a copy of the game for that, though, you can use your same characters and progress between the two platforms will be synced.